# Are the usize/isize types in Rust guaranteed to always be either 32 or 64 bits?

Tags: rust

If I compile a program targeting a 16 bit architecture, will `std::mem::size_of::<usize>()` return 2, or is it guaranteed (via a specification, RFC, or otherwise) to always return 4 or 8?

Comment: Seems like that is still an open issue: see https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1748

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the answer is currently **no**, based on [rust-lang/rust#1748](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1748). The issue regards assumptions about the size of `usize`, and is currently open (and implicitly unresolved). All platforms with tier 1 support are currently 32 or 64 bit [[ref](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html)].

However, [rust-lang/rust#49305](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/49305) assumes pointers to be at least 16 bits. That is *not* based on any Rust RFC or specification, as it is mentioned that

> [the conversion's] infallibility is supported by the C99 standard which (indirectly) requires pointers to be at least 16 bits.

As this pull request was merged in 2018, it seems this is the current (though unofficial) policy is that `usize` and `isize` can be assumed to be at least 16 bits, which would mean `std::mem::size_of::<usize>()` is *not guaranteed* to return 4 or 8. On the contrary, it seems like it can already return 2, though that seems to be the lower bound.

Comment: Tbh. I don't think an 8 bit address bus would make much sense anyway.

Comment: Sure, as far as I can tell there's nothing prohibiting usize from being equivalent to a u128 at some point in the future, though.

Answer (score 15):

This is what [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#primitive-data-layout) has to say about `usize`:

> `usize` and `isize` have a size big enough to contain every address on the target platform. For example, on a 32 bit target, this is 4 bytes and on a 64 bit target, this is 8 bytes.

Note that the phrasing doesn't exclude sizes other than 4 bytes or 8 bytes. Indeed, Rust already [supports a platform](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html) with 16-bit `usize`: `msp430-none-elf` (the MSP430 is a 16-bit microcontroller).

If you want to perform conditional compilation based on the size of pointers, you can use the [`target_pointer_width`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_pointer_width) configuration option. Here's a sample usage from the [`core`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/760226733e940cb375f791e894fbb554555eeb01/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L4602-L4625) library:

```
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "16")]
#[lang = "usize"]
impl usize {
    uint_impl! { usize, u16, 16, 65535, "", "", 4, "0xa003", "0x3a", "0x1234", "0x3412", "0x2c48",
        "[0x34, 0x12]", "[0x12, 0x34]",
        usize_isize_to_xe_bytes_doc!(), usize_isize_from_xe_bytes_doc!() }
}
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
#[lang = "usize"]
impl usize {
    uint_impl! { usize, u32, 32, 4294967295, "", "", 8, "0x10000b3", "0xb301", "0x12345678",
        "0x78563412", "0x1e6a2c48", "[0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12]", "[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]",
        usize_isize_to_xe_bytes_doc!(), usize_isize_from_xe_bytes_doc!() }
}

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
#[lang = "usize"]
impl usize {
    uint_impl! { usize, u64, 64, 18446744073709551615, "", "", 12, "0xaa00000000006e1", "0x6e10aa",
        "0x1234567890123456", "0x5634129078563412", "0x6a2c48091e6a2c48",
        "[0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0x90, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12]",
         "[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56]",
        usize_isize_to_xe_bytes_doc!(), usize_isize_from_xe_bytes_doc!() }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I could definitely perform conditional compilation, I was just interested if it was _guaranteed_ (not even just current behavior) that `usize` would be able to store at least 2^32 values.